# My function is not storing data in the dataframe in R. however, it is printing the output

Tags: r, function

Check the code and the output in the picture. what could be the issue for not populating the dataframe. My function is not storing data in the dataframe in R. However, it is printing the output.

```
library(vcd)
data("Arthritis")

data_frame_Treatment = data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(levels(Arthritis$Treatment)), ncol = 3, dimnames = list(c(),c("Levels","Frequency","Mean of ages"))),stringsAsFactors = F)


fill_data_frame = function(levelname, rowNum, columnNum){
  
  data_subset = subset(Arthritis,Arthritis[,columnNum] == levelname)
  
  data_frame_Treatment[rowNum,1] = levelname
  print(data_frame_Treatment[rowNum, 1])
  
  data_frame_Treatment[rowNum,2] = nrow(data_subset)
  print(data_frame_Treatment[rowNum, 2])
  
  data_frame_Treatment[rowNum,3] = mean(data_subset[["Age"]])
  print(data_frame_Treatment[rowNum, 3])
 
}


for (i in levels(Arthritis$Treatment)) {
  if(i == "Placebo"){
    fill_data_frame("Placebo",1,2)
  } else {
    fill_data_frame("Treated",2,2)
  }
}
```

[image: check the outputs]

Comment: You don't return anything in the function. You have to `return` something at the end. At the moment you are just printing them (as per the `print()` commands)

Comment: It seems that you design a fucntion to manipulate values of a dataframe in the global environment. To simply make it work, remove all the `print()` lines and replace `=` with `<<-`. But note that this's not a regular usage of functions.

Comment: yes, the print is for testing purpose only. i wanted to check if my function is processing the data. and could you elaborate how to return ?

Comment: @DarrenTsai well actually i want this function to put data in the data frame. and i am using R studio that supports "=" for assignment operator. if i run the each line of code individually, it does populate the dataframe but when these are in the function. so i was wondering if any expert here could find the issue.

Comment: @FannyKhan `=` in the function only influences local objects. If you want to manipulate values in the global environment, use `<<-` instead.